# Spark SQL query struct fields with duplicate name

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql

[Updates: Seems below problem only affecting Databricks 10.x with the literal view explode (to expand the array), the query works as expected in Databricks 9.x]

When querying a df from JSON as struct, below error shows up:

```
Error running query
Ambiguous reference to fields StructField(value,StringType,true), StructField(value,StringType,true)
```

This is because I am querying two fields having the same name (but not the same path)

```
select
postlist.string_map_data.Likes.value as PostLikeCount,
postlist.string_map_data.Comments.value as PostCommentCount
from newschema.insta_post_insights
    lateral view explode(organic_insights_posts) AS postlist
```

So two "value" are duplicate are causing this error. Any Spark SQL query method that I could produce something like

| PostLikeCount | PostCommentCount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

Renaming the source df probably works the best but that is affecting ETL process which is not ideal in this case. Appreciate if someone could help. The JSON data is a typical Instagram data export as below

```
"organic_insights_posts": [
    {"string_map_data": {
        "Creation timestamp": {
          "href": "",
          "value": "",
          "timestamp": 123456789
        },
        "Profile visits": {
          "href": "",
          "value": "--",
          "timestamp": 0
        },
        "Impressions": {
          "href": "",
          "value": "--",
          "timestamp": 0
        },
        "Follows": {
          "href": "",
          "value": "--",
          "timestamp": 0
        },
        "Accounts reached": {
          "href": "",
          "value": "--",
          "timestamp": 0
        },
        "Saves": {
          "href": "",
          "value": "1",
          "timestamp": 0
        },
        "Likes": {
          "href": "",
          "value": "1",
          "timestamp": 0
        },
        "Comments": {
          "href": "",
          "value": "1",
          "timestamp": 0
        }
```